# This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable even close check

Tags: android, realm

I have a strange error produced from the realm instance. I saw some related questions with same error log, but couldn't find an answer for my own case. Even I make close check of realm instance it still gives me this particular error. Any idea or help is appreciated.

```
if (defaultRealm != null && !defaultRealm.isClosed())
        {
            if (defaultRealm.where(FactUserDataRM.class).equalTo("id", theFact.getUserData().getId()).findFirst().isLiked() == b)
            {
                Log.i(Statics.LOG_TAG, "New value is same with the realm nothing is going to change now");

                new ArticleLikeUpdateJSON(null, ((int) theFact.getId()), this, b,
                        null, null, null, theFact)
                        .execute(Statics.LikeCountUpdate + theFact.getId());

                likeCount_Checkbox.setChecked(b);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                LikeStateChanged(b);
            }
        }
```

Error log in Firebase

```
io.realm.BaseRealm.checkIfValid (BaseRealm.java:437)
io.realm.com_viyatek_ultimatefacts_RealmDataModels_FactRMRealmProxy.realmGet$userData (com_viyatek_ultimatefacts_RealmDataModels_FactRMRealmProxy.java:256)
com.viyatek.ultimatefacts.RealmDataModels.FactRM.getUserData (FactRM.java:57)
com.viyatek.ultimatefacts.Activites.ArticleActivity.ControlRealm (ArticleActivity.java:461)
com.viyatek.ultimatefacts.Activites.ArticleActivity.CheckBoxChangeProcess (ArticleActivity.java:457)
com.viyatek.ultimatefacts.Activites.ArticleActivity.onCheckedChanged (ArticleActivity.java:428)
```

Comment: It says that `theFact` is obtained from a Realm instance that had been closed.

Comment: Yes it is. The strange part is before I am doing anything with theFact, I am making close check. But it seems it doesn't work

Comment: theFact is obtained from defaultRealm

Comment: Is "theFact.isValid()" code would help me? to find out, the realm associated to the Fact is closed?

Comment: Can you add code for `FactRM` data type, particularly `getUserData` function. Check if `theFact.realm` is still open and valid also.

Comment: You need to change your code in such a way that you don't end up invalidating the Realm instances on the thread when you are still using managed RealmObject instances that would be invalidated if the Realm is closed. But yes, `isValid()` would hide this issue from you.

Comment: Thank you. I will redesign my handling of realm lifecycle